# overriding .sqliterc .mode on sqlite3 batch mode

Tags: sqlite, batch-processing

I have a .sqliterc file with .mode column.

Now despite I run

```
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' .....
```

It is padded with spaces instead tabs:

```
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' ..... | cat -A

 -- Loading resources from /home/xyz/.sqliterc
 Ensembl_Gene_ID     gene      $
 ------------------  ----------$
 ENSMUSG00000038503  Mesdc2    $
 ENSMUSG00000038503  Mesdc2    $
 ENSMUSG00000038503  Mesdc2    $
 ENSMUSG00000038503  Mesdc2    $
```

How can override some of the options in .sqlitrc. If it is possible I would rather don't  switch off .sqliterc but overwrite some options.

Comment: I can substitute the spaces with tabs ` | perl -lpe "s/ +/\t/g; s/\s+$//" | cat -A` but if I have a void field I would join two columns with the substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-separator $'\t'` option does not take effect because in `column` output mode, `each record is shown on a separate line with the data aligned in columns`.

The sqlite3 command line option does overwrite the settings in .sqliterc. Try overwriting the output mode using `-list` option, then you will see `-separator $'\t'` takes effect.

```
sqlite3 -separator $'\t' -list  -header  test.db "select * from test" | cat -A
```

The output is in `list` mode, `\t` as the separator:

```
-- Loading resources from /home/test/.sqliterc
Ensembl_Gene_ID^Igene$
ENSMUSG00000038503^IMesdc2$
ENSMUSG00000038503^IMesdc2$
ENSMUSG00000038503^IMesdc2$
ENSMUSG00000038503^IMesdc2$
```

Comment: Thanks I had the wrong impression that setting -separator I was setting implicitly -list mode.